# Some questions about investing

Tags: investing, trading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to start with personal finance?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9139/where-to-start-with-personal-finance)

I have started saving up some money and would like to utilize it better than to just put it in a savings account. How can someone learn more about investing. As a student, I would prefer if the resources were all free. For someone below the age of 25, what is the best form of investment. Also, what is a good amount of money to start trading with?

Comment: A couple of my past answers might be useful, http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9139/where-to-start-with-personal-finance/9151#9151 or http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7616/saving-for-retirement-how-much-is-enough/7618#7618 for example.

Comment: @Mahendru I closed this as a duplicate because its a bit too broad as currently asked and the other question Havoc mentioned covers this pretty well.  The more objective your question is, the better.

Comment: The other questions talk about people who are not students and are over the age of 25, but its fine, the other posts are quite helpful as well. Thanks.

Comment: we had at least one if not two questions about just this sort of thing (including being students) in just the last week or two, look back through the list of questions and you should find them.   Here's one example http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9905/a-university-student-wondering-if-investing-in-stocks-is-a-good-idea and here is another http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9918/automatic-investments-for-cheap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the best form of investment? It only depends on your goals...

The perfect amount of money depends also on your particular situation. The first thing you should start getting familiar with is the notion of portfolio and diversification. Managing risk is also fundamental especially with the current market funkiness...

Start looking at index based ETFs -Exchange Traded Funds- and Balanced Mutual Funds to begin with. Many discounted online brokerage companies in the USA offer good training and knowledge centers. Some of them will also let you practice with a demo account that let you invest virtual money to make you feel comfortable with the interface and also with investing in general.

Comment: What are some good online resources to learn more abut portfolio, diversification and the different types of funds? A quick Google search returns too many results..

Comment: That's a good question... Maybe you can start with these two: http://www.abcsofinvesting.net/asset-allocation-strategies/ and http://www.investopedia.com/